# How to determine if there exists a non-zero vector in the kernel

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, circulant-matrices

If you are given a $0$-$1$  circulant matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns, is there an efficient way of determining if there exists a non-zero $\{-1,0,1\}$-vector in its kernel?

---

Could this problem in fact be NP-complete?

---

**July 10 2015**

Emil Jeřábek argues in the comments that the problem is (very) unlikely to be NP-complete.  Its complexity still remains open however.

Comment: The problem is certainly NP-complete for general matrices, see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20277. The restriction to circulant matrices could well make a difference, but I can’t tell.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The reductions in that linked question do not seem to apply here unless there is a clever trick I have missed.

Comment: Here's a matrix-free reformulation:  Given a set $S$ in $Z/nZ$, are there disjoint sets $T$ and $U$ such that $|(S+i)\cap T|=|(S+i)\cap U|$ for all $i$?  Here, $S$ encodes the first row of the matrix, $T$ encodes the positive part of the vector, and $U$ encodes the negative part of the vector.

Comment: @MattF. — (And the union of $T$ and $U$ should be non-empty.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ denote your circulant matrix and $P$ the cyclic permutation matrix as defined in 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix
such that $P^n=I$ is the identity matrix. After rotating the first 1 to the first entry your $C$ assumes the form
$C=I+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\,P^k,$
where $a_k\in\{0,1\}$.

Now assume there is a non-zero $\{-1,0,1\}$-vector $v$ in the kernel $K$, then also $P^k\,v\in K$, because $C\,P^k\,v ~=~ P^k\,C\,v~=~0$. Also, $v$ cannot contain only 0,-1  entries.
It is therefore possible to rotate the first 1 of $v$ to the first position.
After doing this, consider the matrix
$V=I+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} v_k\,P^k.$

From the previous properties follows that $C\, V ~=~0.$ It is therefore possible to expand $C\, V $ in terms of $P$ using $P^n=I$ and solve the linear system $C\, V ~=~0$ for $v_k$.
If there is a vector $v$ with $v_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ in the kernel $K$ then it is a solution to this linear system of $n$ equations in $n-1$ variables, and this can readily be checked in polynomial time.
This provides an efficient polynomial algorithm to test whether a solution exists and to find it.

Addition:
Here is a proof-of-concept Mathematica Code to find the $v_k$:

```
n = 500;
res = Reap[Do[
c = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {n}]; (* Create random first row of C  *)
While[c[[1]] == 0, c = RotateLeft[c]]; (* rotate such that c[[1]]=1 *)
Clear[v]; vv = Table[v[k], {k, 1, n}]; vv[[1]] = 1; (* variable rotated v *)
lc = ListConvolve[c, vv, {1, -1}, 0]; (* Polynomial multiplication *)
lc = Take[lc, n] + Append[Drop[lc, n], 0];  (* Using P^n =Id  *)
s = Solve[lc == 0, Drop[vv, 1]];  (* Solve linear system for v *)
If[s != {}, Sow[{c, vv /. s}]], {20}]][[2, 1]] (* collect cases with solution *)
```

One solution for n=500 is

```
{{{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,  
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0}, {{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}}}}
```

To test that this really is a solution:

```
Table[RotateLeft[res[[1, 1]], k].res[[1, 2, 1]], {k, 1, n}]
```

results in

```
 {0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0}
```

Multiple solutions can occur and require some polishing, but all is easily done in polynomial time.

Comment: Thank you for this! Does your approach extend to partial circulant matrices (as the bounty offerer seems to be interested in these)?  A partial circulant matrix is just the first $m \leq n$ rows of a circulant matrix.

Comment: I ran your code on various $n$.  The output suggests that positive answers occur *only* when either the first row of the matrix or the vector are periodic, with period properly dividing $n$.  If so, that would probably establish polynomial time easily.

Comment: Thank you as well.  I have been working through it and I don't yet understand why "If a solution exists then all $v_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$." is true. I would be very grateful if you could expand this part.  I would also be very interested to know if this approach worked for matrices with fewer rows than columns.

Comment: @MattF: This is a correct observation. The method essentially searches special zero divisors in $\mathbf{Z} / n\mathbf{Z} [X]$ which has only trivial solutions if $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Raphael : What I wanted to say is: If a solution to the original problem exists, then a unique solution of the linear system has only elements in $ \{-1,0,1\}$. I was not aware of the empirical fact that it actually never has other unique solutions. Because this method uses the specific properties of square circulant matrices it does not directly generalize to $n\times m$ matrices.

Comment: Is it in fact possible that we just need to look for singular matrices in this square circulant $\{0,1\}$ case?

Comment: What happens if $C$ is highly degenerate? I mean, how is the new system any better than the old one except you know that you have 1 in the first position (which, after all, is not a big deal because if you are totally stupid and just say that it is *somewhere*, all you lose is a factor of $n$). Am I missing something?

Comment: @fedja I also don't get it unless it turns out that $\{0,1\}$ square circulant matrices have a non-zero $\{-1,0,1\}$ vector in their kernel if and only if they are singular. I wrote some code to look at small cases and the relationship holds for them. Do you think it could be true in general?

Comment: @Raphael Our matrix is degenerate iff the corresponding polynomial $P(z)$ has a root that is also the $n$'th root of unity. Let $q|n$ be the order of that root of unity. Then we would normally think that $(z^q-1)/(z-1)|P$, in which case we are fine because $(z^n-1)/(z^q-1)$ has all other roots. However, if $q$ is composite, we can only say that the corresponding cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_q$ divides $P$, so the product of the remaining cyclotomic polynomials must divide $Q$ and we have any chance for an example only if $(z^q-1)/\Phi_q(z)$ has large coefficients, which happens not very soon.

Comment: @fedja I apologize if this is obvious to others, but what is $Q$ in your comment?

Comment: @dorothy Oh, sorry. That is the "solution polynomial" with coefficients $0,\pm 1$ that must have all other roots of unity (not the ones in $P$) to make the (discrete Fourier transform of) the convolution vanish.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is the associated polynomial to a circulant matrix $C$, then the kernel of $C$ is spanned by vectors
$$v_i = (1,w_i,w_i^2, \dots, w_i^{n-1})$$
where the $w_i$ range through all $n$-th roots of unity that are also roots of $f(x)$.

This gives an explicit description of the kernel, and so determining whether $ \{-1,0,1\}$-vector lies in its kernel can be done by solving a bunch of linear equations.

**Added later, in response to comments:** We don't really want to solve $3^n$ linear equations (and I apologise for suggesting that this could be in any way interpreted as efficient). Two points:

1. If the kernel has dimension $d$, then one can reduce the system to $3^d$ linear equations so this naive approach is OK when the kernel is small.
2. We should be able to use the fact that $C$ is a $\{0,1\}$-matrix: if $f$ has any root at all, then it will be divisible by an irreducible cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_\ell$ of some degree $d$, thus the kernel will contain $v_1,\dots, v_d$, the vectors corresponding to the roots of this cyclotomic polynomial. I asserted earlier that the sum of these will be a $\{0,1,-1\}$-vector. This was wrong, however some progress can be made:

   - If $\ell=2^a$ for some integer $a$, then the sum of the corresponding vectors is a multiple of a a $\{0,1,-1\}$-vector and we are done.
   - If $\ell=3\cdot 2^a$ for some integer $a$, then an alternating sum seems to  be a multiple of a a $\{0,1,-1\}$-vector and, again, we are done. (Although I don't have time to check this for $\ell>6$ just now.)

In particular, if $n=2^a$ or $3\cdot 2^a$, then one has a non-trivial $\{0,1,-1\}$-vector in the kernel whenever the kernel is non-trivial. And this, of course, can be checked in polynomial time. Whether one can extend this to account for all $n$, I do not know.

Comment: Yes, but how many linear equations? If it's one system of equations for each vector, that's $3^n$ systems of equations, and one may not consider that to be efficient. Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @Gerry, you are quite right, of course. I don't know what the OP considers efficient, so I can't say any more...

Comment: If you consider $3^n$ to be an efficient time, then you might as well just check all $\{-1,0,1\}$-vectors.

Comment: ha! good point!

Comment: I just mean by efficient polynomial in $n$ .

Comment: if the cyclotomic polynomial has degree 3 or 6, then the difference of corresponding vectors works. I guess if it has degree $3\cdot 2^a$, then an alternating sum may work...

Comment: I believe the general form of what you are doing with the cyclotomic polynomials is as follows. Let $\omega$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity, and $I=\{i<n:f(\omega^i)\}$. If a vector in the kernel $u=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_iv_i$ is rational, it is invariant under the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\omega)/\mathbb Q)$. Thus, $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$ if $\omega^i$ and $\omega^j$ are both primitive $\ell$th roots. In other words, $u$ is a (wlog rational) linear combination of the integer vectors $u_\ell=(u_{\ell,0},\dots,u_{\ell,n-1})$, where $\ell\mid n$, $\Phi_\ell\mid f$, and $u_{\ell,k}$ is ...

Comment: ... the Ramanujan sum $\sum_{i<\ell,(i,\ell)=1}\omega^{ik(n/\ell)}=\sum_{d|(\ell,k)}\mu(\ell/d)d$. In general, $u_\ell$ are not $\{-1,0,1\}$-valued. This reduces the problem to finding out whether there is a nontrivial $\{-1,0,1\}$ vector that is a linear combination of particular integer vectors, but this is in general still an NP-complete problem, so one would need to know something more to solve it efficiently.

Comment: There is some hope this is possible: since the answer depends only on $\{\ell:\ell\mid n,\Phi_\ell\mid f\}$ and not anything else about the matrix, and $n$ has at most $n^{O(1/\log\log n)}$ divisors, the problem has subexponential circuit complexity $2^{n^{O(1/\log\log n)}}$, so it should *not* be NP-complete under plausible complexity-theoretic assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote above is not quite right. The $\alpha_i$ are in $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ rather than $\mathbb Q$, so the invariance of $u$ only gives that if $\sigma$ in the Galois group makes $\sigma(\omega^i)=\omega^j$, then $\sigma(\alpha_i)=\alpha_j$. The ultimate upshot of this is that the rational kernel is generated by not just the $u_\ell$ vectors, but also their cyclic shifts (which it obviously contains). Only $\varphi(\ell)$ shifts of $u_\ell$ are linearly independent, of course.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  Does this mean it is still plausibly NP-complete?

Comment: @dorothy: That’s quite unlikely. It is generally believed that NP-complete problems require exponential-size circuits, and it would be a major result to show the opposite.